# tablespace PIT recovery for non archived ORACLE DB

Tags: database, oracle, recovery, tablespace

Our development guys have dropped all the objects of a ORACLE Schema in a non archived ORACLE DB. All I have is Tablespace to which this schema points to and also the Data file but the data file timestamp are updated with current time. if there any chances if I do PIT recovery of this tablespace in non archived DB. if yes, can anyone tell me the steps for the same?

Comment: Do you have backup? Physical? Logical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running on 10g or later? If so, you might be able to recover tables and related objects from the recycle bin (assuming it was enabled):

```
SELECT * FROM RECYCLEBIN;
```

If you're lucky you can do this:

```
FLASHBACK TABLE your_table TO BEFORE DROP;
```

There's lots in the documentation. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#ADMIN01506).

This won't recover packages or other program units. For those you need scripts.

---

Obviously there is teaching here for you as well as the developers. You need source control, archive logging and/or backups for *all environments* not just Production. These things are tedious and apparently expensive, but they are priceless when you actually need them.

Comment: Hello APC, Many thanks but neither are we using FLASHBACK or ARCHIVELOG. Yeah we have space constraints issue in DEV UNIX packages. but I restored the schema using impdp/REMAP SCHEMA feature of my weekly backup of whole DB. The DEV team was okay with it.